# only works with a breakpoint-Xamarin Studio

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin

this code:

```
  try{
            _player.Stop();
            _player.Release();
            _player.Dispose();
                _player = null;
            }
            catch( Exception)
            {
            }
        }
```

only works if I put a breakpoint at _Player.Stop(). why? I am using Xamarin Studio it I do not use a breakpoint it says: 'jobject' must not be IntPtr.Zero. Parameter name: jobject

what does that mean ? and why does it only work if I have a break point ?

also it does not like this

if ( _Play.Isplaying) // it always give me this error : IntPtr.Zero. Parameter name: jobject

> ```
>         button.Click += delegate {
>             if( flag == 1)
>             {
>                 return;
>             }
>             ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o=> Stopped());
>             int temp = Convert.ToInt16(test1.Text) ;
>             temp = temp * 44100 *60 *2;
>             if( tone1 ==0)
>             {
>                 trackW = new whitenoise(temp);
>                 trackW.Frequency = Num; //Convert.ToDouble(Beattext.Text);
>                 ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o=> trackW.play());
>                 flag = 1;
>             }else if (tone1 ==1)
>             {
>                 trackP = new PinkNoise(temp);
>                 trackP.Frequency = Num;//Convert.ToDouble(Beattext.Text);
>                 ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o=> trackP.play());
>                 flag = 1;
>             }
>             else if (tone1 ==2 )
>             {
>             trackB = new BrownNoise(temp);
>                 trackB.Frequency =Num;// Convert.ToDouble(Beattext.Text);
>             ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o=> trackB.play());
>             flag = 1;
>             }
>             else if (tone1 ==3 )
>             {
>                 _player = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.dark);
>                 _player.Start();
>                 //flag = 1;
>             }
>             else if (tone1 ==4 )
>             {
>                 _player2 = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.thunder);
>                 _player2.Start();
>                 //flag = 1;
>             }
>         };
> ```

Comment: Does the player not start right away?  Maybe you're trying to stop it before it's started.  Where are you creating the player and how are you starting it?

Comment: it start right away but it does not stop.. will sometimes it does stop

Comment: Can you post the code where it is created, the code where it is started, and when the above code is being called?

Comment: also I created it in the play button

Comment: Jim did you see the play button ?

Comment: Hmm looks fine.  Could you be stopping it twice?  That also might not be obvious in the debugger.

Comment: you know I think you might be right about  doing stopping twice. my  mouse something click twice. but with i use the key pad it seem to work.

Comment: but why would it not work in the 1st place?

Comment: This sounds like a race condition since you are using multiple threads. Any reason you are using the threadpool instead of Task.Run or async/await?

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin.iOS `MediaPlayer` is a namespace, not a type. So it's unclear which type is being created with:

```
_player = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.dark);
```

Now several media-related types are asynchronous, i.e. when you call `Stop` it will **ask** the player to stop and then return immediately. IOW you'll get back control before the actual stop action is completed. That likely explain why putting a breakpoint make your code works (it introduce delays that make it looks like it works synchronously).

```
_player.Release();
```

Don't ever call `Release` manually (there should be a compiler warning for that line). It's required in very special circumstances where you're doing manual memory management (e.g. calling `Retain`). That's very low level (XI internals needs it) and **very** rarely required in user code.

```
_player.Dispose();
```

That's also not the right place to call `Dispose` as the `Stop` might not have completed it's job (and disposing the instance could create problem as it's still being used, stopping, natively). Some types provide events that will tell you when things (like stop) actually happens. Even then you might just want to let the GC do it's job.